# VS Code: Unable to install flask

Tags: python, flask, visual-studio-code, site-packages

I'm not using a virtual environment, & have tried selecting the appropriate python interpreter.

When I do a `python3 -m pip install flask`,

my terminal says `Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.10.1->flask) (1.1.1)`

However, I receive this error message: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask' which traces back to VSCode being unable to import "flask" for some reason.

[image: Image of error message from PyLint]

Would appreciate any help!

Comment: Is Python 3.8 on PATH and the one that VSC is using?

Comment: @monsieuralfonse64 python 3.8 is on PATH & is the one VSC is using, but i realised that the flask package is installed under python 3.8 even though my machine/vscode is using python 3.7

this is what it shows me: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages

Comment: but my python 3.7 is stored in /usr/local/bin/python -- for some reason python 3.7 doesn't show up in the "Versions" folder above. do you have any advice abt reconciliating the 2? thanks (-:

Comment: Clarify which version of python you're using in VSC

Comment: @monsieuralfonse64 3.7 & it follows the same path of where 3.7 python is stored in my computer

Comment: @codinggirl123 vscode lets you pick any version of python on your PATH. On the very bottom of the vscode window you'll see something like "Python 3.8.5 64-bit" if you click on it you can select a different interpreter.